# competing examples in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

Is it intended that people write competing examples for one topic?

My question was sparked by

[Visual Studio - Hello World](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/15/compile-and-run-your-first-c-sharp-program/3170/visual-studio-hello-world)
and
[Hello World in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/15/compile-and-run-your-first-c-sharp-program/3543/hello-world-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Yeah, I agree, it kind of looks more like a regular Question with multiple Answers, except there's no question text, just a title.  There's not even an option to vote to close/delete/flag/merge examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's voting ain't there? So you get to pick which example you find more useful. Or decide they're both great. Or decide they're both terrible.

Over time, the most useful examples should rise to the top...

Comment: remains the inconsistent wording - that hurts my eyes :-)

Comment: That kind of sidesteps the issue of whether we want competing examples at all.  Why not just merge them?  Or close/delete one?  For questions, there is a system in place to close duplicates, but no such system seems to exist for examples.

Comment: What would that even *do*, @Brendan? Deletion exists, and can be used readily, although I would encourage folks to be judicious about it. If there's no clear winner and they're not *exactly* the same, see how the voting plays out...

Comment: @Shog9 It would do the same thing that closing duplicates does -- funnel people to the best answer and consolidate answers and edits to a single place instead of having them spread out over multiple questions/examples.  I didn't see any close/delete options on examples (though that may be because I don't have delete privileges), just the flag option for spam/offensive content.

Comment: Click edit, then click the little "trashcan" icon to delete, @Brendan. Having a "pointer" to an example *on the same page* is just a waste though.

Comment: @Shog9  Thanks. Yeah, I'm not proposing we tag examples as "duplicates", they should just be closed and deleted.

Comment: More or less identical examples just clutter the list of examples (unless you hide those which are not in the say top 10). Also why wasting time and effort to make an almost duplicate when you could have improved the original instead. So deleting those makes sense in my eyes.